# Drawing an specific feynman diagram with TikZ (LaTeX)

Tags: tikz-feynman

I was looking for a diagram such as shown in the first picture, but I just get the one that is in the second picture with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}[large]
\vertex (b);
\vertex [left=of b] (a);
\vertex [above right=of a] (i1);
\vertex [below right=of a] (i2);
\vertex (d);
\vertex [right=of d] (c);
\vertex [above left=of c] (j1);
\vertex [below left=of c] (j2);
\diagram* {
(a) [crossed dot] -- [double] (b) -- [gluon] (j1),
(a) [crossed dot] -- [double] {(i1),(i2)},

(d) -- [double] (c) [crossed dot],
(j1) -- [double] (c) [crossed dot] -- [double] (j2),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I separate the central lines and draw the correct vertex?

Thank you in advance!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Please try copying and compiling your posted code into a new file. If it doesn‘t compile, extend it as needed until it does AND still shows your problem. Finally please update your code fragment in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved it by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}[large]
\vertex (b);
\vertex [left=of b, crossed dot,draw=black,fill=white] (a) {};
\vertex [above right=of a] (i1);
\vertex [below right=of a] (i2);
\vertex [right=3 cm of a](d);
\vertex [right=of d, crossed dot,draw=black,fill=white] (c) {};
\vertex [above left=of c] (j1);
\vertex [below left=of c] (j2);
\diagram* {
(a) -- [double] (b) -- [gluon] (j1),
(a) -- [double] {(i1),(i2)},

(d) -- [double] (c),
(j1) -- [double] (c) -- [double] (j2),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).